# Compile multiple executables from multiple source directories to single bin directory using makefile

Tags: makefile, fortran, gfortran

I'm trying to create a makefile for a suite of programs that I am working on.  The programs are all written in fortran and the source files are contained in different directories.  I can't seem how to figure out how to get things to work.  My current sumfile is

```
#Compiler and compiler flag variables
FCOMP=/usr/local/bin/gfortran
F_FLAGS=-O2 -fbounds-check -Wall 
F_FLAGSDB=-g -fbounds-check -Wall

#paths to libraries
COMMON_LIB=/usr/local/lib/libspc_common.a
SPICE_LIB=/usr/local/lib/spicelib.a

# Paths to directories
BIN_DIR=BIN

# Get file names of component source files
#get names of files in src1
FORT_FILES=$(wildcard ./SRC1/*.f)
#get names of files in src2 
FORTFILES+=$(wildcard ./SRC2/*.f)   
#get names of files in src3 
FORTFILES+=$(wildcard ./SRC3/*.f)   

#get file names for output
EXE_FILES=$(addprefix $(BIN_DIR),$(notdir $(patsubst %.f, % , $(FORTFILES))))

# make commands
# Set the default option to compile the library with optimization
default: all

# create all command 
all: $(EXE_FILES)
    @echo toolkit has been built with optimization

#If compiling for debugging replace the compiler flags to remove optimization and add debugging
debug: F_FLAGS=$(F_FLAGSDB)
#Run compiler with debugging flags
debug: $(EXE_FILES)
    @echo toolkit has been built with debugging

# Compile all of the source files into executables 
$(EXE_FILES): % : %.f
    $(FCOMP) $(F_FLAGS) $^ $(COMMON_LIB) $(SPICE_LIB) -o $(BIN_DIR)/$@

# install the library in /usr/local/lib
install: 
    cp -p $(BIN_DIR)* /usr/local/bin/toolkit/   

# remove executable files for a clean build
clean:
    rm $(BIN_DIR)*
```

The problem I am running into is that I get the following error when I try to run make:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `Display.f', needed by `Display'.  Stop.
```

which I am assuming is because I have lost the directory that the source file comes from.  Can someone help me here?  I am totally stuck and don't know how to proceed.

In addition (this is more a general question about make), is there a way to tell make to recompile everything if the COMMON_LIB changes?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm not a makefile expert, but it looks like `$(EXE_FILES)` includes `Display.f` when you probably want it to include `Display`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose your source files are

```
SRC1/alpha.f
SRC1/beta.f
SRC2/gamma.f
SRC3/delta.f
```

**1) There is a flaw here:**

```
EXE_FILES=$(addprefix $(BIN_DIR),$(notdir $(patsubst %.f, % , $(FORTFILES))))
```

This will produce

```
BINalpha BINbeta BINgamma BINdelta
```

when I think you intended

```
BIN/alpha BIN/beta BIN/gamma BIN/delta
```

A simple fix:

```
EXE_FILES=$(addprefix $(BIN_DIR)/,$(notdir $(patsubst %.f, % , $(FORTFILES))))
```

**2) Now look at the static pattern rule:**

```
$(EXE_FILES): % : %.f
    ...
```

So to build `BIN/alpha`, Make must first find `BIN/alpha.f`, which doesn't exist. To make it look for `alpha.f`, do this:

```
$(EXE_FILES): $(BIN_DIR)/% : %.f
    ...
```

**3) How to find the sources?**

You could do some delicate coding to help Make remember where it found `alpha.f`, but there's no need when we can use [the vpath directive](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Selective-Search):

```
vpath %.f SRC1 SRC2 SRC3
```

**4) One last look at that rule:**

This command:

```
$(FCOMP) $(F_FLAGS) $^ $(COMMON_LIB) $(SPICE_LIB) -o $(BIN_DIR)/$@
```

Will produce e.g. `BIN/BIN/alpha`, which is silly. [**A non-PHONY Make rule should produce a file whose name is the target of the rule.**](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/rules-of-makefiles/) It prevents a lot of trouble.

```
$(FCOMP) $(F_FLAGS) $^ $(COMMON_LIB) $(SPICE_LIB) -o $@
```

A few further refinements may be possible, once you have this working perfectly.